# How to create an autohotkey entry that has a double-colon ("::") in its output?

Tags: autohotkey

All of these autohotkey entries **work fine**:

```
:r0*:uuu::[url=][/url]{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}

:r0*:hhh::[h][/h]{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}

:r0*:iii::[i][/i]{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}

:r0*:bbb::[b][/b]{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}
```

But this one does not work, apparently because of a **conflict** with the "**::**" that I am trying to output:

```
:r0*:shh::qdev::show();{LEFT}{LEFT}
```

since this works with only one colon:

```
:r0*:shh::qdev:show();{LEFT}{LEFT}
```

**But how can I e.g. escape the colons so that I can have a double colon in the output?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a backtick to escape the double colon:

```
:r0*:shh::qdev`::show();{LEFT}{LEFT}
```

You can change the escape character:

```
#EscapeChar \  ; Change it to be backslash instead of the default of accent (`).
```